# How to make an element children the same height with another element's child?

Tags: jquery, css, elementor

I'm currently building a pricing table and I wondered how I can make the child elements the same height per row. I'm using a page builder as the website is built in WordPress and the row fields are in a different column. So basically it's not structured like a table and I would want to make each row the same height.
[image]

I've tried this [matchHeight](https://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) library but I couldn't make it work with the child elements per column.

Here's a pen [demo](https://codepen.io/leonardpbdigital/pen/QWvogGz)

```
$('.col > div').matchHeight();
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're required to do columns then rows instead of rows then columns?  Switching it to rows then columns can solve your problem without javascript.

Comment: I mean I was thinking it would be my last resort just in case I couldn't find a solution. Another reason could be on responsive view as I want them to be separated per column.

Comment: what happens to them responsively as a column?  You can do some pretty insane things with flexbox.

Comment: Pretty much should be the same as how it currently shows on desktop but will be in a single column on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add CSS property ***min-height*** to the `.col > div` selector => `min-height: calc(100% / var(--col-rows));`. `var(--col-rows)` would be set in your CSS using a css variable coming from the DOM via javascript.

```css
.col {
/* target the div within the .col in your scss */
> div {
    /* the --col-rows variable will be used to calculate 
       the number of elements we have in our rows 
       so they are all take up the same amount of space */      
    min-height: calc(100% / var(--col-rows));
```

Setting the css variable using JavaScript to get the amount of rows you have and then place that number into your `:root` style using `setProperty()`

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--col-rows`, maxNum);
```

The CSS ***`:root`*** element variable:

```css
:root {
  --col-rows: 0; /* this will be set using JS to read the 
                    amount of rows present in the DOM */
}
```

Getting the number of rows:

```js
// get all the .col elements
const columnRows = document.querySelectorAll('.col');
// instantiate an array and set it to empty, this will
// hold all the divs lengths or "rows"
const lengthArr = [];
// iterate over the rows and get the length of each columns rows
columnRows.forEach(item => {
  let count = item.children.length
  // push each row length into the array
  lengthArr.push(count);
});
// get the maximum amount of rows
const maxNum = Math.max(...lengthArr);
// set the --col-rows CSS variable using the root HTML element
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--col-rows`, maxNum);
```

Now the number of rows is dynamically created using JS and layed out using CSS using the CSS variable set in the `.col > div` ***min-height*** property.

```js
// get all the .col elements
const columnRows = document.querySelectorAll('.col');

// instantiate an array and set it to empty, this will
// hold allt he div lengths or "rows"
const lengthArr = [];

// iterate over the rows and get the length of each columns rows
columnRows.forEach(item => {
  let count = item.children.length
  // push each row length into the array
  lengthArr.push(count);
});

// get the maximum amount of rows
const maxNum = Math.max(...lengthArr);

// set the --col-rows CSS variable using the root HTML element
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--col-rows`, maxNum);
```

```css
:root {
  --col-rows: 0;
  /* this will be set using JS */
}

body {
  font-family: "Inter";
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper .col {
  width: 30%;
}

.wrapper .col~.col {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .col>div {
  /* the --col-rows variable will be used to calculate 
     the number of elements we have in our rows 
     so they are all take up the same amount of space */
  min-height: calc(100% / var(--col-rows));
  padding: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

.wrapper .col>div:first-child {
  background: red;
}

.wrapper .col>div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.wrapper .col>div:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.wrapper .col>div:nth-child(4) {
  background: blueviolet;
}

.wrapper .col>div:last-child {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="col">
      <div># of virtual attendee tickets (to use as giveaways, remote staff, etc.)</div>
      <div>Named as sponsor on event website</div>
      <div>Chair drop (materials provided by sponsor)</div>
      <div>Location of sponsor booth (first come, first served)</div>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div>John Doe and event team staff wear sponsor T-shirt to Welcome Reception (T-shirt provided by sponsor) </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
      <div>9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
      <div>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div>Choice of location</div>
      <div>More prominent location on website and conference app</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>some text</div>
      <div>Different text here</div>
      <div>Yet more text that explains something different</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example might do what you need:

https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/wvdOrwz

Basically the idea is that there are multiple headers that aren't shown for 4 columns/large screens and only shown in 2 columns/smaller screens. Additionally under the 2 columns we re-order the cells so all the gold/plat/diamond are grouped together.

Under normal circumstances, I use 25% and 50% but because the borders are taken into account the widths are a bit smaller to produce the desired results.  If this is an issue, don't put borders on the cells, put another element (div) inside the sells and add a border to them instead.

Since I wasn't exactly sure what you meant, it's probably not perfect but should give you plenty to go on to give the desired results.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="col">
              
                <div class="o1"># of virtual attendee tickets (to use as giveaways, remote staff, etc.)</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2"># of virtual attendee tickets (to use as giveaways, remote staff, etc.)</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3"># of virtual attendee tickets (to use as giveaways, remote staff, etc.)</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>

                <div class="o1">Choice of location</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">Choice of location</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">Choice of location</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>
              
                <div class="o1">Named as sponsor on event website</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">Named as sponsor on event website</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">Named as sponsor on event website</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>

                <div class="o1">More prominent location on website and conference app</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">More prominent location on website and conference app</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">More prominent location on website and conference app</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>

              
                <div class="o1">Chair drop (materials provided by sponsor)</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">Chair drop (materials provided by sponsor)</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">Chair drop (materials provided by sponsor)</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>

                <div class="o1">Location of sponsor booth (first come, first served)</div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">Location of sponsor booth (first come, first served)</div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">Location of sponsor booth (first come, first served)</div>
                <div class="o3">Diamond</div>

                <div class="o1">John Doe and event team staff wear sponsor T-shirt to Welcome Reception (T-shirt provided by sponsor) </div>
                <div class="o1">Gold</div>
                <div class="rs o2">John Doe and event team staff wear sponsor T-shirt to Welcome Reception (T-shirt provided by sponsor) </div>
                <div class="o2">Platinum</div>
                <div class="rs o3">John Doe and event team staff wear sponsor T-shirt to Welcome Reception (T-shirt provided by sponsor) </div>
                <div class="o1 o3">Diamond</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
body {
  font-family: "Inter";
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  &-inner {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    > div {
      padding: 20px 0;
      border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      width: 21%;
    }
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .wrapper {
    &-inner {
      > .col {
        > div {
          &.rs {
            display: none;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrapper {
    &-inner {
      > .col {
        > div {
          width: 48%;
          
          &.o1 {
            order: 1;
          }
          &.o2 {
            order: 2;
          }
          &.o3 {
            order: 3;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```